# Sensor - µC - compatibility

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, accelerometer

I want to connect an "Adafruit Feather M0 Adalogger" to an acceleromter (IIS3DWB/ STEVAL-MKI208V1K).

IIS3DWB (Sensor): SPI, ODR: 26.7 kHz

- Is the µC compatible for this sensor?
- In general, at which specs do I have to look at in order to know if a sensor is compatible to a certain µC?
- Product page [Adafruit Feather M0 Adalogger](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-adalogger)
- [IIS3DWB Datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/389/dm00501492-1799236.pdf)
- [STEVAL-MKI208V1K Datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/389/steval-mki208v1k-1699408.pdf)

Comment: Does the logger have an SPI interface? It's as simple as that.

Comment: @Andyaka There's no question about max. output data rate and processor compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to identify when working out compatibility between ICs.
The first is the IO standards applied. There are a great many (LVTTL, PECL, etc), some are compatible and some are not.
The second is what communications protocol is required.

[image]

Table 1 is taken from the datasheet for the accelerometer device. As you can see, there is SPI and an I2C interface (as well 2 interrupts). As the datasheet states that you won't have full capability using the I2C interface, SPI is the communications protocol that needs to be used.

[image]

Table 4 shows the electrical characteristics for the device. This shows the Input and Output Voltage level for Digital High and Low. As you can see, this is related to what VDD_IO is set to.

So, your microcontroller needs to have a SPI port and be able to have Voltage IO characteristics that match the above.

Your Devkit has an ATSAMD21G18 onboard. As luck would have it, it has a built in SPI port so that's the communications protocol sorted.

[image]

The ports for this device are highly configurable. Section 23 of the datasheet is helpful here.
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAM_D21_DA1_Family_DataSheet_DS40001882F.pdf

Needless to say, you need to set the right port configuration settings to enable the right functionality (Input, Output, etc).

[image]

The above table shows the electrical characteristics for the microcontroller. Like the Accel, it too has configurable input and output voltage highs. However, the Dev Kit it is mounted on supplies 3V3 to the device giving you what VDD is.

You can now calculate what your input and output voltages are, and compare them to the Accel IO voltage levels. I'll leave this as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Adafruit Feather M0 Adalogger can interface an IIS3DWB accelerometer.

This accelerometer can be interfaced with either SPI or I2C, both of which are supported by ATSAMD21G18 and its pins taken out in the Feather M0 Adalogger.

The Feather M0 also has GPIOs that can generate interrupts based on the signals of the INT1 and INT2 pins of the accelerometers, which is user programmable.

The Feather board can also provide the necessary 3.3V supply.

Comment: Why is the necessary supply 3.3V? Vdd_max = 3.6V; Vdd_IO max = Vdd + 0.1V = 3.7V; Dgital high level input voltage = 0,7*3.7V = 2,59V; High level output voltage = Vdd_IO - 0.2V = 3.5V